# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::books does not exist.(laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I am beginner of laravel, I want to store a book to books database, but after click button, it shows "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::books does not exist." What am I missing?
here are my codes.

**BookController**

```
public function create()
{
    return view('books.create');
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'book' => 'required|max:255',
        'category' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required|numeric',
        'price'=>'required|numeric',
        'info'=>'required'
    ]);
    //$request->user()->member()->books()->create([
    $member=auth()->user()->member()->get();
    $member->books()->create([
        'book' => $request->book,
        'category' => $request->category,
        'quantity' => $request->quantity,
        'price'=>$request->price,
        'info'=>$request->info
    ]);

    return redirect('shops')->with('success', 'successful');
}
```

**books.create**

```
<form action="{{route('books.store')}}" method="POST" role="form">

        @csrf
        @method('POST')
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="book">name：</label>
            <input id="book" name="book" class="form-control" placeholder="enter book name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="category">category：</label>
            <input id="category" name="category" class="form-control" placeholder="enter category">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="quantity">quantity：</label>
            <input id="quantity" name="quantity" class="form-control" placeholder="enter quantity">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="price">price：</label>
            <input id="price" name="price" class="form-control" placeholder="enter price">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="info">info：</label>
            <textarea id="info" name="info" class="form-control" rows="10" placeholder="enter info"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn-sm btn-primary">create</button>
    </form>
```

User and Member is one to one relation, and Book belongs to one Member

**Book Model**

```
public function member()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Member::class);
}
protected $fillable = ['book','category','quantity','price','info'];
```

**Member Model**

```
public function books()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Book::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**User Model**

```
 public function member()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Member::class);
}
```

books,user and member migration

**books migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('books', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedInteger('member_id');
        $table->foreign('member_id')->references('id')->on('members')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->integer('price');
        $table->string('path');
        $table->string('info');
        $table->string('category');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**member migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('members', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->unsignedbigInteger('user_id');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->string('sex');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('tel');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

**user migration**

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
        $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... `auth()->user()->member()->create()` directly use like this don't save in  variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$member=auth()->user()->member()->get();` returns a collection not an object of Member class. Use `$member=auth()->user()->member()->first();` or `$member=auth()->user()->member;`

Try this

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'book' => 'required|max:255',
        'category' => 'required',
        'quantity' => 'required|numeric',
        'price'=>'required|numeric',
        'info'=>'required'
    ]);
    
    $member=auth()->user()->member;
    if($member){
        $member->books()->create([
            'book' => $request->book,
            'category' => $request->category,
            'quantity' => $request->quantity,
            'price'=>$request->price,
            'info'=>$request->info
        ]);
    

        return redirect('shops')->with('success', 'successful');
    }

    //Member is not found, return with error
    return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Member not found');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are receiving a Collection from this chain of calls:

```
$member = auth()->user()->member()->get();
```

`get` is going to always return a Collection when called on a relationship method. If you want a single model you can call `first` instead:

```
$member = auth()->user()->member()->first();
```

Though `first` could return `null` so you may need to check that.

Another method to access the result of this relationship would be to use the dynamic property for the relationship `member`:

```
$member = auth()->user()->member;
```

Since that relationship is defined as a `HasOne` it knows to load it for a single result or `null`.

Assuming `$member` isn't `null` at this point you should be fine with the rest how it is.

Answer (score 1):

That error is due to the fact that this call `$member=auth()->user()->member()->get();`. It's supposed to return a `Collection` of `Member`.

So when you try to call `books` on a collection hold by the variable `member` It' won't succeed as `Illuminate\Support\Collection`  Class doesn't define a method `books` you have to loop trought that collection by using a `foreach` loop or a `each` or `map` method from `Collection`.

```
$member->each(function($member){
    $member->books()->create([
        //
    ]);
});
```

Or has you have already define in `User` Model that `user` will always have a single Member by using `hasOne` method.

So you can use  `auth()->user()->member()->first();` which return a single instance of type `Member` on which you call `books` method but with that you have to be sure that the Authenticated use has already one member which is attached to him to avoid any error. even though that is the case you can always check if variable `$member` is not null with an `if`  statement

```
$member = auth()->user()->member()->first();
if($member){
    // here you can have access to `books`
    $member->books()->create([
        //...
    ]);        
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaining! i got it :), and i fixed the problem! this's my first ask question in here, and i learn very much , thank you all guys!!