# Do i need a One-to-Many polymorphic relationship?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I've got a problem i can't get through, here are my models:

Cloth.php​

```
public function selling(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Selling::class);
}
```

Selling.php​

```
public function clothes(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Cloth::class);
}
```

​And now it's anything ok and pretty basic... but then came this model:

Accessory.php​

```
public function selling(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Selling::class);
}
```

And now it's the problem: I need (i think) a polymorphic relationship but i can't understand how to make it in this specific case.
I have 2 starting models to morph to 1 model but every example i found have 1 starting model to morph to 2 models.
Do i need a polymorphic relationship?
I can't really get out of this.

Thanks!

Comment: Refer to https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations in this case instead of `posts` and `videos` you have `clothes` and `accessories` and instead of `comments` you have `selling`

Comment: @apokryfos already tried but i can't get it to work tbh

Comment: I think you need a many to many polymorphic structure. Follow the doc here; https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations. Still, if you couldn't achieve what you want, please share your code so we can check. But, can't say for certain, until I know what exactly you want to achieve. However, if you think of it as a 2 starting model to morph into 1, the reverse of this is possible too.

Comment: @AkmalArzhang it should be a one-to-many (?) because one selling has more products while one product belongs to only one selling

Comment: @AkmalArzhang I need a relationship to get cloths and accessories at once

Comment: @Musamba If I am understanding you well, you have 2 tables accessories and clothes and in one sales cart you want to sell from both tables? Please correct me if I am wrong. If that is the case, why not add a type field in your database to specify if this product is a cloth or an accessory, instead of creating 2 separate tables?

Comment: @AkmalArzhang Yes, correct. Because they have different properties but if i can't manage to get a polymorphic relation i'll make one table for both with a bunch of nullable fields but just as last resource

Answer (score 1):

You are basically looking for a one to many polymorphic relationship. Here is how to do it:

Let's say your tables are structured like bellow;

```
Schema::create('sellings', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->integer('relation_id');
            $table->string('relation_type');
            $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('accessories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('details');
            $table->timestamps();
});

Schema::create('cloths', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
});
```

Selling.php

```
public function relation(){
   return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Cloth.php

```
public function selling(){
     return $this->morphOne(Selling::class, 'relation');
}
```

Accessories.php

```
public function selling(){
     return $this->morphOne(Selling::class, 'relation');
}
```

Then, you can query using bellow approach;

```
$selling = Selling::findOrFail(1)->relation;
```

Now when you `dd($selling)` you get exactly what you are looking for from a correspondent table;

[image]

Please remember that the relation_type field needs to exactly correspond the model. See bellow screenshot for example;
[image]

What happens here is when you create a polymorphic function called test the database fields need to follow with test_type corresponding to model and test_id corresponding to the id of the model/database table.

Comment: Yup, i was trying something like that but i've got another problem: is it possible that when i get all clothes (Cloth::all()) it does not return a builder query? After defining a polymorphic relationship i get this: "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::clothes does not exist. (View: /app/resources/views/livewire/clothes/clothes.blade.php)" I can't even paginate the result because it returns a collection

Comment: @Musamba I updated the answer to describe the scenario in full. For your question, please refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65318616/method-illuminate-database-eloquent-collectionbooks-does-not-exist-laravel

Comment: Since a sale may correspond to a specific product either cloth or an accessory, you will need to query with Selling::All() or get() for example and in its correspondent view inside your foreach loop take benefit of ->relation in iteration. I hope I have made it clear enough.

Comment: Thanks man, i tried this solution but i need for sure a many to many polymorphic relationship. EDIT: No, i don't need a many to many as i need to specify a single model in every relationship.